# Bot Email channel Duplicate messages

Tags: botframework

We have created a Bot and have configured channels like Skype and WebChat. Bot works fine. We have added one email channel and have attached a O365 email-ID to it. Now when we send a email to this O365 email ID then Bot replies back and its all good. But have observed that Bot is actually sending duplicate emails as if its running in a loop. Has anyone faced this, or a similar issue?

Comment: Please edit your answer and post the code being used to reply.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in BotFramework v4. Also it doesn't happen every time and very hard to replicate while investigation.